# how to stop js created borders to effect other elements?

Tags: css, hover, border

There is a horizontal menu in my website and items inside it have no border. but I want it to have 1px border on mouseover, so when I move the mouse on it, this newly created border moves other elements to the left, about 2px (because `border-right` = `border-left` = 1px).

this is my code

```
<div id="library_category_wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is css

```
#library_category_wrapper ul 
    {
        list-style: none;
        float: right;
        position: relative; 
        top:5px;
        margin: auto;
    }

#library_category_wrapper ul li 
    {
        display: inline;
        margin-left:8px;
        padding : 4px;
    }

#library_category_wrapper li:hover
    {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border : 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        border-radius : 4px 4px 4px 4px;
        box-shadow : 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        text-shadow : 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.796), 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.298);
        padding : 4px;
    }
```

this is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stallman3738/Pn8uw/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a 'transparent' border to the default LI state:

```
#library_category_wrapper ul li {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pn8uw/2/

Answer (score 3):

You can simply put a transparent border on the normal state like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Pn8uw/1/

```
#library_category_wrapper ul li {
    border : 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: @opznhaarlems' answer achieves the exact same thing, but with better browser support, so best to go with that.

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez, Mohammad already use rgba in is original CSS, so there is no reason not to use it.

Comment: Well yeah, in places where there is no alternative. Here, `transparent` achieves *precisely* the same thing in a more consistent fashion. So why wouldn't you use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reduce the padding on hover. Add the following property instead of your padding: 4px;

```
#library_category_wrapper li:hover {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pn8uw/3/)

Comment: The other answers that add a transparent border are modifying the default LI state. You essentially have 5px padding instead of 4px on the default LI state. If you truly want to keep the same padding of 4px for default state, you need to either reduce the default state padding by 1px and use the transparent border, or reduce the hover state padding to 3px to match the default state.